# Keyboard Not Working in Bootcamp

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, bootcamp

I just installed Bootcamp and Windows 7 on my MacBook Pro (13 inch, 2010), and booted into the OS. The keyboard and mouse worked fine, but because there were no drivers, things like multitouch and the two-finger mouse click didn't work - this is as expected.

I went back into OS X Lion and downloaded the Windows Support package to my thumb drive, rebooted, and installed the driver package and the Boot Camp Control Panel. After I had restarted, my keyboard wasn't working.

The weird thing is, the F-keys *do* work and function correctly (brightness, volume, etc). If I change those keys to perform the F-key functions in the control panel (ie. require holding Fn+F1 to change brightness), the F-keys work correctly.

Any of the keys *below* the F-key row do not work at all. They don't type anything, no matter what program I am in. The Caps Lock key *does* light up when I toggle it on and off.

I've tried going into the Device Manager and uninstalling the Keyboard driver and then scanning for hardware changes (which reinstalls the Apple Keyboard driver), I've uninstalled and deleted the driver (and then reinstalled it from the package in the WindowsSupport folder), and nothing is working. The keyboard appears as the Apple Keyboard in the device manager. The trackpad and everything works fine as well.

I checked the Language settings and it is set to United States (English).

Is there anything else I can try to get the keyboard working?

- Windows 7 64bit (*not* SP1, yet)
- MacBook Pro 13 inch 2010
- 8 GB RAM
- 250gb HDD, with 55gb partitioned for Windows

OS X Lion (10.7.3) is installed as well.

Comment: You can try to post this question on apple forums, because it can be a bug in bootcamp drivers.

Comment: What version of Boot Camp are you using? Also, how much drive space do you have available in your Boot Camp partition?

Answer (score 2):

**Before you do any of the steps mentioned below the line-break, check the bootcamp control panel first!!!**

When in Windows, after everything is installed and done, do the following:

1. Click 'Start ' (the windows logo-button in the bottom left corner)
2. Type 'bootcamp'
3. Open the bootcamp control panel. It will ask for administrator privileges, say 'yes' or 'ok' or whatever
4. Configure the necessary settings for your startup disk, remote, keyboard and trackpad - these are the four tabs you should expect to see when the bootcamp control panel opens.

Your keyboard and trackpad should work (almost) perfectly. If not, read the answer that follows.

---

When you installed Windows the specific bootcamp drivers should have been installed automatically from your Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard) DVD or 10.7 (Lion) DMG in the process. I would recommend trying to:

1. Remove/Delete the drivers in Windows Device Manager
2. Insert or mount the OSX DVD or DMG
3. Restart your system (booting into Windows).

The correct bootcamp drivers should then be installed automatically from the OSX DVD. If the drivers were not installed, browse for them on the OSX DVD.

If all else fails you can always try re-installing Windows, and from there should be able to determine during the process if you have keyboard functionality.

★ The key to having the **correct** drivers working in bootcamp is installing them specifically from the OSX DVD or DMG.

---

The Mac OS X 10.6 and 10.7 Boot Camp Software includes these Mac drivers for Windows:

```
Apple Bluetooth
Apple Keyboard Support
Apple Remote Driver
Apple Trackpad
Atheros 802.11 Wireless
ATI Graphics
Boot Camp control panel for Microsoft Windows
Boot Camp System Task Notification item (System Tray)
Broadcom Wireless
Intel Chipset Software
Intel Integrated Graphics
iSight Camera
Marvel Yukon Ethernet
nVidia Graphics
Cirrus Logic Audio
Realtek Audio
SigmaTel Audio
Startup Disk control panel for Microsoft Windows
```

---

- [Boot Camp 4.0, OS X Lion: Frequently asked questions](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4818)
- [Boot Camp 3.0, Mac OS X 10.6: Frequently asked questions](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3777)

Comment: I don't know about 2010 macbook, but in 2011 they don't have an OSX install DVD.

Comment: @geotavros, Snow Leopard 10.6.x, Lion 10.7.x

Comment: Apple shows instructions for creating an install disc on the FAQ; I've used a mounted OS X DMG before, and if you format a flash drive in the proper manner it should work just as well. — hope it helps

Comment: I can't find instructions for creating an install disc using the FAQ link you provided.

Comment: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4407

Comment: the link you gave shows how to burn bootcamp drivers on DVD. I meant OSX Lion install DVD. There is no OSX Lion install DVD going with 2011 macbook

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3020/discussion-between-geotavros-and-ioi)

Comment: So I just booted back into Windows, uninstalled and deleted the keyboard driver, restarted, and installed the driver from my OS X install DVD, and the keyboard started working again. BUT, immediately after the install completed and I could use my keyboard, my TRACKPAD stopped working. Wonderful. After uninstalling, rebooting, and reinstalling the trackpad drivers, the keyboard stopped working again. I'm just going to give up and reinstall Windows at this point, and instead of downloading the newer Bootcamp drivers from Apple, I'll use my install disc drivers... I'll post back when that's done.

Answer (score 1):

Your driver may be not the good one for your Macbook. Try to go to Apple Support...

- 32-bit: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1443
- 64-bit: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1442

If it works, you're good!

**IF IT DOESN'T WORK**

Try updating the driver and select it manually in the list, select a driver like `Standard PS/2 Keyboard`. It must fix your bug. You won't have <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> keys for Volume, Brightness, etc. but your keyboard must work

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't a very technical answer... But I was having the same problem.  I booted into the Mac OS, removed the drive partition with bootcamp assistant, then started over, and it worked perfectly the second time.  I literally changed nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off any Apple Bluetooth device that might interfere with your Mac keyboard, since an Apple bluetooth keyboard will not support more devices for it to be connected to.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Windows icon and select device manager. Under bluetooth disable Apple Broadcom Built-in Bluetooth.
Keyboard should start working.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a guide for making an install disc for Mac OS X 10.7.3

http://lifehacker.com/5823096/how-to-burn-your-own-lion-install-dvd-or-flash-drive

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.